# Exception while trying to get value from a json object in java webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services

When i tried to get the value from my json object in my java webservice side i am getting some runtime  exceptions,PLease find the exception i am getting below:
When i tried to get the value from my json object in my java webservice side i am getting some runtime  exceptions,
Please find my json object below:

```
{"data":[{"userid":657,"name":"Eliina","username":"Admin","aim_name":" Eliina ","aim_title":"Administrator","password":"eli456456","role":1,"rolename":"Client Ain","clientno":"540","id":8,"client_name":"Eliina","defaulturl":"clientsettings.htm","attempts":0,"aimaccess":1}]}
```

please find the java method i wrote:

```
public void insertList(String ip, JSONObject loginresult) 
{  
    try{
        String n = loginresult.getString("data");
    } catch( JSONException je ) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PLease find the exception i am getting below:

```
30-Sep-2015 10:27:11.007 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /home/ty02/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/MobileService.xml has finished in 2,217 ms
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["username"] not found.
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:487)
    at com.zimmer.mobileservice.resources.Login.insertauditList(Login.java:84)
    at com.zimmer.mobileservice.resources.Login.checkLogin(Login.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `insertauditList` there the exception comes from.

Comment: error is not in the above java method... it is some where else where you are requesting username and you are not getting it...

Comment: I think your log was different. I remember yesterday you have post same question trying to get 'username' from jsonObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input JSON is,

```
{"data":[{"userid":657,"name":"Eliina","username":"Admin","aim_name":" Eliina ","aim_title":"Administrator","password":"eli456456","role":1,"rolename":"Client Ain","clientno":"540","id":8,"client_name":"Eliina","defaulturl":"clientsettings.htm","attempts":0,"aimaccess":1}]}
```

So which means for key `data,` value is the `JSONArray`, but you are trying to get `JSONArray as String` so you are facing such exception. What you need to do is, need to get the value as JSONArray like,

```
JSONArray value = loginresult.getJSONArray("data");
```

**Edited Answer:**

Now the value JSONArray contains the array object from which you can get for a `key` like,

```
JSONArray value = loginresult.getJSONArray("data");
String userId = ((JSONObject) value.get(0)).getString("userid");
```

Better to check for `hasKey check` and `array size check` to avoid nasty exceptions.

Comment: Thanks,what if i need to get the userid?

Comment: String user_id =loginresult.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("userid");

Comment: If you read the stacktrace, you will see that the exception is not from this code snipped: `JSONObject["username"] not found.` `at com.zimmer.mobileservice.resources.Login.insertauditList(Login.java:84)
`

Answer (score 0):

The "data" object you trying get is array in json. you will get value as below.

```
jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")
```

Comment: If you read the stacktrace, you will see that the exception is not from this code snipped: `JSONObject["username"] not found.` `at com.zimmer.mobileservice.resources.Login.insertauditList(Login.java:84)`

Answer (score 0):

This could be most generalized way of doing,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
user =  mapper.readValue(loginresult.toString(), User.class);
```

user is a POJO class which has all getter setter fields that are there in your input.